# Using a Service Reference in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

i have added a service ref in my VB.NET application.

i can see the objects in the object browser. i need to log in first to obtain a session ID.

when I try

```
dim client as new serviceReference1.IGPSBulkData
```

I get an error

> 'New cannot be used on an interface'.

IGPSBulkdata is the only option that includes the login function so Im not sure how to make this call

any ideas?

Comment: Is this your service or someone else's if the latter, have they provided any documentation?

Comment: not sure about the specifics of VB.NET, but in case of C# when you connect the service you get both the client interface and the default implementation of that interface. Try looking inside your generated code for something resembling the default client implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a service reference several classes are being generated from the service' WSDL. Take a closer look at the generated code  There will be something like `GPSBulkDataClient`.

This generated client class can be used to communicate with the service.

Comment: thank you there is indeed a GPSBulkDataClient and using that i can now connect and return data. Its a GPS system i am connecting to. if i run a function that returns muliple trips, how do i traverse the trips to get some elements i.e. start date

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct; you cannot instantiate an `Interface`.

If you open *Object Browser* in Visual Studio and search for `IGPSBulkData` you should be presented with a list of classes which implement it. From there you can instantiate your `client` object (if that's what you need to do with that class).

So if there was a class called `GPSBulkDataThing` which implements `IGPSBulkData` your code might resemble:

```
Dim client as serviceReference1.IGPSBulkData = new GPSBulkDataThing(maybe with some arguments here)
```